# Dynamic configurations refresh for a python application

Tags: python, flask

I am developing a python application (in a SaaS model), using flask framework and some simple worker applications which consume messages from some message bus.
for those type of services I would like to use some dynamic configurations which don't involve container restart but refresh automatically.

(by saying dynamic configuration - those configurations can be set on some DB and there could be a thread which check for changes and update those configurations in a time of need - those configurations are dynamic and not environment variables)
is there some kind of open source which do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Absolutely no idea what you're asking

Comment: I think he mean reloading the configuration while the app is running instead of restarting the container.

Comment: exactly - meaning those configurations are dynamically being loaded / refresh on change.
the obvious and easy solution might be using environment variables - but I don't want the contatiner to restart

Comment: What configuration values do you want to load dynamically?  `some dynamic configurations which don't involve container restart but refresh automatically.`  Can you clarify this?  Are you trying to configure the environment or the task behaviour?

Comment: I think that I found what I was looking for
consul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution that I was looking for is a open source named Consul.
for more information visit https://www.consul.io/

Thanks